# Automatically filled form in class-based view

Tags: python, django

I want to automatically fill some form in class-based view and save in database.

post function in my view

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_2 = self.form_class_2(self.request.POST)
        if form_2.is_valid():
            keyword = form_2.cleaned_data['keyword']
            books = self.search(keyword)
            if books:
                for book in books:
                    title = self.add_title(book)
                    form = self.form_class(initial={"title": title})
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('add_books'))

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('import_books'))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('index_books'))

        return reverse_lazy('import_books')
```

my form

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ()
```

my form_2

```
class SearchBookForm(forms.Form):
    keyword = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=75,
        verbose_name='Book title')
    published_date = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        validators=[check_if_value_is_date, max_year_validator],
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Publishing date')
    pages = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[check_if_value_is_negative],
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Number of pages')
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Language')
```

And this is how my form looks before validation:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_title">Book title:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="title" value="Harry Potter i Kamień F
ilozoficzny" maxlength="75" required id="id_title"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_published_date">Publishing date:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="published_date" maxleng
th="10" id="id_published_date"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_pages">Number of pages:</label></th><td><input type="number" name="pages" id="id_pages"></td></tr
>
<tr><th><label for="id_language">Language:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="language" maxlength="2" id="id_langu
age"></td></tr>
```

Basically I have 2 forms. form 2 is used to input value which is used as argument in my search function. then this search function return .json, then i took some value from this .json and assign to "title" then this title is my initial data for form. And everything works fine until part with validation. My form isn't valid but when I print my form before validation part I see that my initial data is in form as expected.

Comment: Can you please post your form code?

Comment: I added form and model

Comment: Are both `form_2` and `form` instances of `BookForm`? If not, what are they? Also, can you post a sample of `self.request.POST`?

Comment: I added how looks form_2, this form is basically only to receive in my view value from  html template, sample self.request.POST is np. Harry Potter , and it works fine because search function return nice .json with data from google api. and title variable = Harry Potter so until momen with validation everything works.

Comment: Can you print out form.errors? What are the errors?

Comment: I don't have any error, its just that form.is_invalid() and then form isn't saved and I got redirect which is activated when form isn't valid. but I added how my form looks after pass initial data but before validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197400/discussion-between-ian-kirkpatrick-and-kuracha).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean errors that were thrown. All form instances have an attribute called errors. It's a list of string messages that is set after you call form.is_valid(). So if you print that out after you call form.is_valid(), it should say why your form is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django by default requires Your fields in the form to be filled out. So `BookForm` requires that you have title, published_date, pages, and language filled out in the form. You instantiate `form` without passing actual input. Yes you pass in the initial, but you don't pass in `request.POST` to it (according to what's here). So your form instantiation should look like

```
form = self.form_class({'title': title, 'published_date': book.published_date, 'pages': book.pages, 'language': book.language})
```

Comment: I also tried this before and it doesn't work, and this self.request.POST probably = None, because, this form isn't displayed in my template and i cant input any data to self.request.POST

Comment: How are you getting data into that form then? Or are you even trying to? Is all you care about the title in that form then? The other fields shouldn't be required?

Comment: All data need to be introduced automatically from .json, so I tried to pass all data by initial. yes for now i just set that only title is required, but its only for test pourposes.If form will work then I will automatically initial rest of fields.

Comment: Ohhhh... well where is your data from .json then?

Comment: search function return this .json and it works fine If I print this function then I see that search() return exactly what I want.

Comment: so the `book` in `for book in books` contains all the desired fields (title, published_date, pages, and language)?

Comment: Yes, but this .json also contain fields that I don't want so I have functions that took only values that I want. and You can see in my printed form that it works because title field have correct value.

Comment: Just updated my answer. I think that's what you're looking for then. Specifically, look at the difference in the `self.form_class(...)` part

Comment: Yes, that works, but I didn't fill all fields for now i just changed initial={"title":title} to just only dict {"title":title}. That works and I see my objects in database.